# mongo cluster slow find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-cluster

we have a three nodes Mongo 3.6.11 cluster with a PSA replica set. we start syncing a newly attached node, syncing starts fast but after a while turned very slowly. during syncing this query is unexpectedly slow:

```
db.Cartable_Task.find(
     { $and: [ { "oprator": { $in: [ "fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab" ] } } ], "deleted": false }
).sort( { "content.officialDate": -1, "_id": -1 }).skip(150).limit(10)
```

and result of explain("executionStats") is :

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "kateb.Cartable_Task",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "deleted" : {
                                            "$eq" : false
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "oprator" : {
                                            "$eq" : "fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab"
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "limitAmount" : 10,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "SKIP",
                                    "skipAmount" : 0,
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "deleted" : 1,
                                                    "oprator" : 1,
                                                    "content.officialDate" : -1,
                                                    "_id" : -1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "deleted_1_oprator_1_content.officialDate_-1__id_-1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                    "deleted" : [ ],
                                                    "oprator" : [ ],
                                                    "content.officialDate" : [ ],
                                                    "_id" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            "isUnique" : false,
                                            "isSparse" : false,
                                            "isPartial" : false,
                                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "deleted" : [
                                                            "[false, false]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "oprator" : [
                                                            "[\"fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab\", \"fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab\"]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "content.officialDate" : [
                                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "_id" : [
                                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ *** ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
            "executionSuccess" : true,
            "nReturned" : 10,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 115425,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 160,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 10,
            "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "nReturned" : 10,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4862,
                    "works" : 161,
                    "advanced" : 10,
                    "needTime" : 150,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 221,
                    "restoreState" : 221,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "limitAmount" : 10,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "nReturned" : 10,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4862,
                            "works" : 160,
                            "advanced" : 10,
                            "needTime" : 150,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 221,
                            "restoreState" : 221,
                            "isEOF" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "docsExamined" : 10,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "SKIP",
                                    "nReturned" : 10,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 280,
                                    "works" : 160,
                                    "advanced" : 10,
                                    "needTime" : 150,
                                    "needYield" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 221,
                                    "restoreState" : 221,
                                    "isEOF" : 0,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "skipAmount" : 0,
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "nReturned" : 160,
                                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 280,
                                            "works" : 160,
                                            "advanced" : 160,
                                            "needTime" : 0,
                                            "needYield" : 0,
                                            "saveState" : 221,
                                            "restoreState" : 221,
                                            "isEOF" : 0,
                                            "invalidates" : 0,
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "deleted" : 1,
                                                    "oprator" : 1,
                                                    "content.officialDate" : -1,
                                                    "_id" : -1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "deleted_1_oprator_1_content.officialDate_-1__id_-1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                    "deleted" : [ ],
                                                    "oprator" : [ ],
                                                    "content.officialDate" : [ ],
                                                    "_id" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            "isUnique" : false,
                                            "isSparse" : false,
                                            "isPartial" : false,
                                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "deleted" : [
                                                            "[false, false]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "oprator" : [
                                                            "[\"fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab\", \"fec48cfa-998c-4c53-b0a6-8a194e3d37ab\"]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "content.officialDate" : [
                                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "_id" : [
                                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                    ]
                                            },
                                            "keysExamined" : 160,
                                            "seeks" : 1,
                                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                            "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "KMongoDb3",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "3.6.11",
            "gitVersion" : "b4339db12bf57ffee5b84a95c6919dbd35fe31c9"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684344748, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1684344748, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
            }
    }
}
```

I checked CPU, Memory and disk IO usage, and none are full.

Comment: This query is executing efficiently (thanks for providing the explain plan), so the slowness is being caused by something else in the system. Probably more of a question for dba.stackexchange.com. If you've added another data bearing member to the PSA set, you may want to remove the arbiter to avoid cache pressure on the storage engine related to the even number of nodes. See also [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/mitigate-psa-performance-issues/)